# praying in a room where there were 2 men who were working on the computer

Tags: salat

assalamu a'laikum. I have my tutions from 3:30pm to 5:30pm. Saying the prayer of asr is preferred for a time being. So i said my prayer at the office room. There were 2 men working. They were not looking at me and i was praying behind them. Is this something wrong?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking our [tour] and checking our [help].